# Xcode : Auto PlayVideo at start up

Tags: iphone, xcode, splash-screen, movie

i want to play a short video as soon as the application launches. It's a short video and a light application so i do not expect any serious delays. However my problem is that although my code works fine wheni test it as an IBAction, it doesn't work when i paste it anywhere else like ViewDidLoad, awakeFromNib, ApplicationDidFinishedLaunching. I am searching all day long for tutorials that work in Xcode 4.2 (ARC enabled) but i couldn't find anything that worked. 
Here is my code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"testmovie" ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

//playercontroller.movieControlMode=MPMovieControlModeHidden;

[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];

playercontroller = nil;
```

If anybody can provide a tutorial or sample code, i would be extremly grateful!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i try this code in ViewDidLoad i get no image, however i get sound for a few seconds (not the whole clip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take out movie player and just use 
[playercontroller play];
if it needs releasing do so as well